# Getting data from within belongs_to/has_many model relationship in Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have an app where each Site belongs to a Trust and a Trust has many Sites.

I'm building the JSON result with Jbuilder like this:

```
    json.array! (@sites) do |site|
        json.id site.id
        json.name site.name
        json.city site.city
        json.state site.state
        json.country site.country
        json.start_date site.start_date
        json.end_date site.end_date
        json.trust site.trust, :id, :name  # throws error here
    end
```

The final line of the block returns an error of NoMethod, "a undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass."

However, the Site model belongs_to :trust and the Trust model has_many :sites.

When I run the Rails console, I can access site.trust.id and site.trust.name as I would expect.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I basically dumped my database and then ran the migrations again. It now works fine.

Any ideas why this would be? It worked fine previously, but then it threw the error. I just want to make sure I don't make the same mistake again.